# Why doesn't my Python script work in game?

Tags: python, screen, reader

I've been trying to make a simple script, it presses the key when the image of the key is visible in the left bottom corner of the screen.

The problem is when I'm in the game (Multi Theft Auto) the script stops working only in the game window. I tried running script/game as administrator, changing resolution, making the game windowed/fullscreen but nothing changes. Here's my code:

```
from numpy import random
import pyautogui
import pydirectinput
import time 
import keyboard 
import random
import win32api, win32con

sleeptime1 = random.uniform(1.05, 2.03)
sleeptime2 = random.uniform(1.04, 2.01)
sleeptime3 = random.uniform(1.02, 2.05)
while True:
    if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('key_a.png', region=(0,580,500,500), grayscale=True, confidence=0.7) != None:
        pydirectinput.press('e')
        time.sleep(sleeptime1)
    if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('key_b.png', region=(0,580,500,500), grayscale=True, confidence=0.7) != None:
        pydirectinput.press('q')
        time.sleep(sleeptime2)
    else:
        pydirectinput.click()
        time.sleep(sleeptime3)
```

Comment: Either the game is implementing anti-cheat protection, or maybe you are breaking something by continually clicking the screen. Why do you have pydirectinput.click() in the else condition?

Comment: @TheConfax It's a mining game, you need to click the LMOUSE button and 3 random keys. When you press all the keys correctly, the image dissapears and you need to click the mouse to mine again.

Answer (score 0):

just run your game as administrator like your python, that should help.